# How do I change the datatype of a newly created column in a view? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql and sql-server

I have created a new column in a view with a case. The problem is the following: I believe that the newly created column has a default datatype.

My question is **how do i define the datatype of a new column when creating it?** I have tried using convert and cast.

```sql
 ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vtbl_dim_vb]
    AS
    SELECT    
      vb_key,ver_login,
      ver_name,
      ver_klass_descr,
      CAST(ver_klass AS varchar(40)) + ' ' + ver_klass_descr AS klass_descr_d,
      store_code,
      store_name,
      CASE WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) = 'S' THEN ver_klass ELSE NULL END AS ver_sector,
      CASE WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) = 'M' THEN ver_klass ELSE NULL END AS ver_metier,
      CASE WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'S' AND LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'M' THEN ver_klass ELSE NULL END AS ver_rayon
    FROM         
      dbo.tbl_dim_vb
```

I have tried to use the cast command but that didn't work:

```
  CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```

I want to know what options i have for the third case.

this is how the code looks like that I tried:

```
CASE WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'S' AND LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'M' THEN ver_klass ELSE NULL END AS CAST ( ver_rayon AS int(10) )
```

I need the newly created column ver_rayon to be an integer datatype.

Thanks a lot for any advice ; )

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vtbl_dim_vb, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.   -- that is the error i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
CAST(
(
  CASE 
  WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'S' AND LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'M' 
  THEN ver_klass 
  ELSE NULL 
  END
) AS INT)
AS ver_rayon
```

Comment: So what have we learn today. Always write the exception in the question:P